# creating a dataframe using lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a dataframe that looks like this excel sheet but I can't figure out how to do so. Here is the code I am attempting to use

```
import pandas as pd 
ls_super = ['Supernatant',total_volume_super_ml, Total_activity_super, total_protein_super_mg, specific_activity_sup, 100, 1]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(ls_super, columns =['Sample','Total Volume','Total activity','Total protein','Specific Activity','percent yield,','purification' 
])
```

[image]

Here is the error message: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_125580/4224246098.py in 
20
21 # list of strings
---> 22 df3 = pd.DataFrame(ls_super, columns =['Sample','Total Volume','Total activity','Total protein','Specific Activity','percent yield,','purification'
23 ])
24

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in **init**(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
709                     )
710                 else:
--> 711                     mgr = ndarray_to_mgr(
712                         data,
713                         index,

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in ndarray_to_mgr(values, index, columns, dtype, copy, typ)
322     )
323
--> 324     _check_values_indices_shape_match(values, index, columns)
325
326     if typ == "array":

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in _check_values_indices_shape_match(values, index, columns)
391         passed = values.shape
392         implied = (len(index), len(columns))
--> 393         raise ValueError(f"Shape of passed values is {passed}, indices imply {implied}")
394
395

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (7, 1), indices imply (7, 7)

Answer (score 3):

**Problem:** the `DataFrame()` constructor insists on interpreting the one-dimensional python list `ls_super` as 1 column and 7 rows ("Shape of passed values is (7, 1)"), as opposed to 1 row with 7 columns (which would have shape=(1, 7)).

**Solution:** add a second set of brackets (`[]`) around your definition of the `ls_super` list. In other words, make `ls_super` a two-dimensional list. The DataFrame constructor then sees a single value in the first dimension, and seven values in the second dimension, producing the desired shape of (1, 7).

```
ls_super = [['Supernatant',1, 2, 3, 4, 100, 1]]

df3 = pd.DataFrame(ls_super, 
                   columns=['Sample', 'Total Volume', 'Total activity', 'Total protein', 'Specific Activity', 'percent yield', 'purification'])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

first_row_list = [
    "Supernatant",
    total_volume_super_ml,
    Total_activity_super,
    total_protein_super_mg,
    specific_activity_sup,
    100,
    1
]

columns = [
    "Sample",
    "Total Volume",
    "Total Activity",
    "Total protein",
    "Specific Activity",
    "percent yield",
    "purification"
]

d = dict(zip(columns, [[f] for f in first_row_list]))
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

or

```
d = {'Sample': ["Supernatant"],
      'Total Volume': [total_volume_super_ml],
      'Total Acitivity': [Total_activity_super],
      'Total protein': [total_protein_super_mg],
      'Specific Activity': [specific_activity_sup],
      'percent yield': [100],
      'purification': [1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

In pandas dataframe your input could be an a list of list.

```
import pandas as pd
from random import uniform

total_volume_super_ml = uniform(0,1)
Total_activity_super = uniform(0,1)
total_protein_super_mg = uniform(0,1)
specific_activity_sup = uniform(0,1)

ls_super = ['Supernatant',total_volume_super_ml, Total_activity_super, total_protein_super_mg, specific_activity_sup, 100, 1]
df3 = pd.DataFrame([ls_super], columns =['Sample','Total Volume','Total activity','Total protein','Specific Activity','percent yield','purification'])
df3
```